# How can I select the first table cell with specific content (cells in different rows)?

Tags: jquery, css, contains

I have a table with several cells with the same content. I would like just to select the first one and do some CSS changes.

The cells are not in the same row (tr)

What I have so far is:

```
jQuery('td:contains("Februar")').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

That works for all the td's with 'Februar'. I tried to select just the first one with :first, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please include your attempt with `:first` - if you did `td:first:contains...` then it likely won't work.  Try also `$("td:contains(...)").first().css...`  [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the lines below will work.

`jQuery('td:contains("Februar")')[0].style.fontWeight = 'Bold';`
or
`jQuery('td:contains("Februar")').first().css('font-weight', 'bold');`
or
`jQuery('td:contains("Februar")').eq(0).css('font-weight', 'Bold');`
or
`jQuery('td:contains("Februar"):first').css('font-weight', 'bold');`

Comment: Thanks, but still all the 'Februar' will be bold with your code? I forgot to mention that the td's are in different rows 'tr', is that the reason?

Comment: I know this question was closed by another user. But if you can share your html on something like codepen and post a link, I can help. Otherwise I’m guessing at the structure of your html that you’re having trouble selecting with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it. You can find the table here: https://schlussgang2.cytracon1.info/resultate/

Comment: on line 1061 (at least that's the line in my dev tools, your file may have php in it), you have this line of code: `jQuery('td:contains("Februar"):first-child').css('font-weight', 'bold');`  The :first-child pseudo-selector is what is causing all the feb's to be bold. Each one of those elements are the first-child within the tr. The code snippets I've included in my answer do not use this pseudo-selector. They all use a different method to select the first element in the document that fits the criteria.

Comment: Sorry, that was a test I forgot to take out.  But unfortunately still not working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like your script is running too early. It works if I run it in the console after the page has loaded (and the table created). Try moving this script to the last line before the body tag closes.